# Start/Setup of chess game getting corrupted

Tags: python

I've spent a long time trying to figure out this issue, I need a fresh pair of eyes and someone who knows python a little better.

I started implementing a chess game to help me learn python, and I've basically only implemented moving pawns and displaying the board.  Here's the issue:

-when I move any of the top players' pawns either 1 or 2 spaces forward, everything is fine.

-when I move any of the bottom players' pawns 2 spaces forward, everything is fine.

-when I move any of the bottom players' pawns 1 space forward, everything goes awry.  On the display, the whole row of the new position turns into pawns, but after printing results, all of the open spots now "belong" to the bottom player (they should belong to no one, 0).

I've tried testing different columns with the same results.

Here's an illustration of the issue:

SETUP

```
1 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
2 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
3 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
4 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
5 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
6 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
7 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
8 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

OK

```
Enter a move [r0,c0,r1,s1]: [2,a,3,a]

1 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
2 [ ][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
3 [P][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
4 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
5 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
6 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
7 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
8 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

OK

```
Enter a move [r0,c0,r1,s1]: [2,a,4,a]

1 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
2 [ ][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
3 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
4 [P][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
5 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
6 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
7 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
8 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

OK

```
Enter a move [r0,c0,r1,s1]: [7,a,5,a]

1 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
2 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
3 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
4 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
5 [P][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
6 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
7 [ ][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
8 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

??NOT OK?? - (after moving, all 'blank' spaces belong to bottom player, and all of row 6 (as shown below) have the type variable set to pawn)

```
Enter a move [r0,c0,r1,s1]: [7,a,6,a]

1 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
2 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
3 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
4 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
5 [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
6 [P][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
7 [ ][P][P][P][P][P][P][P]
8 [R][k][B][K][Q][B][k][R]
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```

And the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

# This is easy to solve with a simple tiny wrapper:
class Callable:
    def __init__(self, anycallable):
        self.__call__ = anycallable

class Piece:
    Arr_Slot = 0
    Row = 0
    Col = 0
    Sym = "[ ]"
    Id = ""
    Player = 0
    def __init__(self, row, col, player):
        self.Row = row
        self.Col = col
        self.Player = player
        self.Arr_Slot = self.Arr_Slot + 1

class Blank(Piece):
    Sym = "[ ]"
    Id  = "Blank"
    Row = 0
    Col = 0
    def __init__(self,row,col):
        self.Row = row
        self.Col = col

class King(Piece):
    Sym = "[K]"
    Id = "King"

class Queen(Piece):
    Sym = "[Q]"
    Id = "Queen"

class Rook(Piece):
    Sym = "[R]"
    Id = "Queen"

class Bishop(Piece):
    Sym = "[B]"
    Id = "Bishop"

class Knight(Piece):
    Sym = "[k]"
    Id = "Knight"

class Pawn(Piece):
    Sym = "[P]"
    Id = "Pawn"
    def TryMove(board,row0,col0,row1,col1):
        type = board.Board[row0][col0].Id
        player = board.Board[row0][col0].Player

    if player == 1:
        if (row1 == (row0+1) or ((row1 == (row0+2)) and row0 == 1)) and (col0 == col1):
            if board.Board[row1][col1].Player != player:
                board.Board[row1][col1].Sym = board.Board[row0][col0].Sym
                board.Board[row1][col1].Id  = board.Board[row0][col0].Id
                board.Board[row1][col1].Player = board.Board[row0][col0].Player
                board.MakeBlank(row0,col0)
                return 1
            else:
                print "Error: Spot taken by same player"
                return 0
        else:
            print "Error: Illegal move"
            return 0
    elif player == 2:
        if (row1 == (row0-1) or ((row1 == (row0-2)) and row0 == 6)) and (col0 == col1):
            if board.Board[row1][col1].Player != player:
                board.Board[row1][col1].Sym = board.Board[row0][col0].Sym
                board.Board[row1][col1].Id  = board.Board[row0][col0].Id
                board.Board[row1][col1].Player = board.Board[row0][col0].Player
                board.MakeBlank(row0,col0)
                return 1
            else:
                print "Error: Spot taken by same player"
                return 0
        else:
            print "Error: Illegal move"
            return 0
    else:
        print "Error: Don't own that spot"
    TryMove = Callable(TryMove)

class Board:
    """The game board"""
    Board_Dims = 8
    Arr_Slot = 0
    Board = []
    def __init__(self):
        self.Board = [[Piece for i in range(self.Board_Dims)] for j in range(self.Board_Dims)]

    def AddPiece(self, Piece):
        self.Board[Piece.Row][Piece.Col] = Piece
        self.Board[Piece.Row][Piece.Col].Arr_Slot = self.Arr_Slot
        self.Arr_Slot = self.Arr_Slot + 1
    def MakeBlank(self,row,col):
        self.Board[row][col].Sym = "[ ]"
        self.Board[row][col].Id = "Blank"
        self.Board[row][col].Player = 0
    def PrintBoard(self):
        sys.stdout.write("\n")
        for i in range(self.Board_Dims):
            sys.stdout.write(str(i+1) + " ")
            for j in range(self.Board_Dims):
                sys.stdout.write(self.Board[i][j].Sym)
            sys.stdout.write("\n")
        sys.stdout.write("   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h\n")
    def TryMove(self, row0, col0, row1, col1):
        type = self.Board[row0][col0].Id
        player = self.Board[row0][col0].Player
        if type == "Blank":
            print "Error: No piece there"
            return 0
        if type == "Pawn":
            return Pawn.TryMove(self,row0,col0,row1,col1)


GameBoard = Board()

GameBoard.AddPiece(King(0,3,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Queen(0,4,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Rook(0,0,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Rook(0,7,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Knight(0,1,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Knight(0,6,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Bishop(0,2,1))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Bishop(0,5,1))
for i in range(GameBoard.Board_Dims):
GameBoard.AddPiece(Pawn(1,i,1))

GameBoard.AddPiece(King(7,3,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Queen(7,4,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Rook(7,0,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Rook(7,7,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Knight(7,1,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Knight(7,6,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Bishop(7,2,2))
GameBoard.AddPiece(Bishop(7,5,2))

for j in range(GameBoard.Board_Dims):
GameBoard.AddPiece(Pawn(6,j,2))

for i in range(2,5):
for j in range(GameBoard.Board_Dims):
    GameBoard.AddPiece(Blank(i,j))

GameBoard.PrintBoard()
result = 1
while 1:
inp = raw_input("Enter a move [r0,c0,r1,s1]: ")
r1 = int(inp[1])-1
c1 = int(ord(inp[3]))-97
r2 = int(inp[5])-1
c2 = int(ord(inp[7]))-97
result = GameBoard.TryMove(r1,c1,r2,c2)
if result == 0:
    print "ERROR: TRY AGAIN"
print GameBoard.Board[3][3].Player
print GameBoard.Board[3][3].Sym
GameBoard.PrintBoard()
```

Commenting these lines out:

```
board.Board[row1][col1].Sym = board.Board[row0][col0].Sym
board.Board[row1][col1].Id  = board.Board[row0][col0].Id
board.Board[row1][col1].Player = board.Board[row0][col0].Player
```

Makes it basically do nothing, so I guess you could say this is where the problem is, but it works for the opposite player, and it's the same code, so that's why I'm uncertain as to whether the problem is actually in these lines.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a completely different approach, instead of using a *board* to store positions and blank *pieces*, I would  store the position information in the 32 `Piece`s generated at setup and only use `Board` class to store the list of pieces on it and to do `Board.draw()`

e.g. something along the lines:

```
class Piece(object):
    symbol = " "
    name = None
    def __init__(self, side, col, row):
        self.side = side
        self.col = col
        self.row = row

class Pawn(Piece):
    symbol = "P"
    name = "Pawn"
    def __init__(self, side, col):
        if side == "white":
            row = 2
        else:
            row = 7
        super(Pawn, self).__init__(self, side, col, row) 
    def move(col, row):
        if self.check_if_move_is_valid(col, row):
            self.col = col
            self.row = row

... same for other pieces...

class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pieces = list()
        for col in range(1,9):
            self.pieces.append(Pawn("white", col))
            self.pieces.append(Pawn("black", col))
        self.pieces.append(Rook("white"), 1)
        self.pieces.append(Rook("black"), 8)
        ... etc ...

    def draw():
        grid = create_empty_grid(8)
        for piece in self.pieces:
             grid[piece.row][piece.col] = piece.symbol
        for row in grid:
             print ''.join(row)
```

Comment: So to check a piece at a given position, does that require looping over all the pieces and looking at their row/column? I guess that was partially my reasoning behind having the board object keep track of the pieces.